# Has anything else written by the Prophet come down to us, besides the Hadith or Qu'ran?

Tags: hadith, prophet-muhammad

For example, in [Sahih Bukhari](http://www.sahih-bukhari.com/Pages/Bukhari_4_52.php) we have the following two reports:

> Allah's Apostle wrote a letter to Caesar saying, "If you reject Islam, you will be responsible for the sins of the peasants (i.e. your people)."

and

> Allah's Apostle sent his letter to Khusrau and ordered his messenger to hand it over to the Governor of Bahrain who was to hand it over to Khusrau. So, when Khusrau read the letter he tore it. Said bin Al-Musaiyab said, "The Prophet then invoked Allah to disperse them with full dispersion, (destroy them (i.e. Khusrau and his followers) severely)".

Is there any independent corroboration about such letters; that is of official contact by the the early *ummah* and the surrounding nations?

Comment: This is kind of broad, an answer can be extremely long,or un-beneficially short as in "Yes".  Perhaps you can make it specifically about the letters?

Comment: @Mujahid: ok, I'll focus it more.

Comment: Asked on [history.se]. http://history.stackexchange.com/q/14190/

Comment: @bleeding fingers: I've asked the moderator to remove that question - they don't see it as a historical question.

Comment: @MoziburUllah the question framing is wrong, besides Hadith and Qur'an. you're comparing those normal letters with Qur'an and Hadith? Please edit that..

Comment: @wiser: I'm not comparing them.

Comment: Yeah I understand that you're not comparing them, but hadith and quran are different and letters to other people are different. Right?

Comment: You can simply ask "Are there any historical evidences about Prophet Muhammad's communication with other nations and tribes through material medium?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_Medina) helps you a little bit out. An important piece of history, the Constitution of Medina was written by Muhammad (pbuh).